# What do I need to add to this facebook og metadata?

Tags: php, facebook

I've got a share button that I am trying to modify to my specific needs. Here is the code.

> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
> xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
> <html>
> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="lotsanumbers" />
> <meta property="og:title" content="FOR SALE"/>
> <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
> <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php"/>
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com.au/ddfut14-1148.jpg"/>
> <meta property="og:description" content="http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php<?php echo $title; ?>" />
> ```

Everything is working as requires except for the og:description. When I debug in facebook facebook is only seeing

> ```
> <meta property="og:description" content="http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php
> ```

it is not scraping

> ```
> <?php echo $title; ?>
> ```

from the same line what am I missing?

Comment: Let me know if you need the work to be done contact me on mohit5783@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[og:description](http://ogp.me/) is a tag that should contain text, you should be doing like:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
//where $title should be a defined variable that contains some text
```

or

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php"); ?>" />
//where your php_test.php file should echo out text
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir I tried both options with the same result ....... Meta Tag <meta property="og:description" content="" /> .... Facebook isn't recognising the PHP